# Functions as pointers in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, function-pointers

This is a question from Learn Objective-C on the Mac...

Functions as pointers

What I typed in, as per the recipe, was:

```
NSString *boolString (BOOL yesNo) {
if (yesNo) { return (@"YES");
} else { return (@"NO");
} } // boolString
```

The pointer asterisk in the first line doesn't seem necessary, yet deleting it results in an error message.  But what does it do?  In

```
 NSString * boolString (yesNo);
```

what seems to be going on is a function is defined as a pointer to an NSString.  The function without the asterisk

```
NSLog (@"are %d and %d different? %@", 5, 5, boolString(areTheyDifferent));
```

returns an NSString of YES or NO.  But how can it return an NSString when it's a pointer?  It might return the ADDRESS of an NSString; or if dereferenced it could return the CONTENTS of that address (an NSString such as YES or NO).  Yet I see no place where it is dereferenced.

Comment: Please format your code next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pointer is for the NSString that the function returns, not for the function itself.

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting of the following code; I'll read up on how to do that ASAP.

You're saying the function works normally, making a string out of a BOOL value, so using the function as an argument for NSLog displays the returned string.

I'm still wondering why a pointer is used at all.

Could I, after the pattern:
 int foo = 7;
     int *pointer = &foo;
     printf("pointer points to the number %d\n", *pointer);

have written something like this?  Though this doesn't seem to work.
 NSString testString = boolString (BOOL yesNo);
        int * ptr = &testString;
 NSLog (@ *ptr );

Comment: To be specific, the boolString function makes a NSString, then returns a pointer to that NSString.  In Objective-C, *all* objects are referred to via pointers.  When you use NSLog to print a NSString, it expects a pointer to a NSString.  That is why the NSString pointer returned by boolString works with NSLog.

Answer (score 3):

The function returns a pointer to an `NSString` object.  In Objective-C you almost never deal with objects directly, only with pointers to them.  As far as you're concerned, `NSString *` is the type you should always be using.

Comment: Sorry for the poor formatting of the following code; I'll read up on how to do that ASAP.

In C++, something like the following would work:

 NSString testString = boolString (BOOL yesNo);
        int * ptr = &testString;
 NSLog (@ *ptr );

In Objective-C, it doesn't.  What I don't get is that

     there seems to be no NSString variable named (like testString) to capture the value boolString() returns;
     and there also is no named pointer (like ptr) to capture the address of the unnamed NSString variable;
     and since the pointer is unnamed, it can't be dereferenced!

Comment: @Rich, that's right.  In Objective-C, you only ever use pointers to objects, never the objects themselves.  I'm sure you'll get used to it.